# How do I add a button to the footer of a section of a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to add a button to the footer of my table view (or at least make the whole thing clickable). How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614946-tableview?language=objc) you must implement the heightForFooterInSection method, otherwise your viewForFooterInSection wouldn't do anything.

**Swift 3**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

guard section == 0 else { return nil } // Can remove if want button for all sections

let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 320, 40))
        let myButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

        myButton.setTitle("My Button", for: .normal)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal) //set the color this is may be different for iOS 7
        myButton.frame = CGRect(0, 0, 130, 30) //set some large width to ur title
        footerView.addSubview(myButton)
        return footerView;

}

func myAction(_ sender : AnyObject) {

}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return 100.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0) //Decide which footer according to your logic 
    {
       UIView *footerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
       UIButton *myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [myButton setTitle:@"Add to other" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//set the color this is may be different for iOS 7
       myButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 30); //set some large width to ur title 
       [footerView addSubview: myButton];
       return footerView;
    }
}

- (void)myAction:(id)sender
{
      NSLog(@"add to charity");
}
```

Comment: FWIW I think between your heighForFooterInSection and the footerView frame's height...the heightForFooterView would aupercede and make your height be 100 not 40

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: How can i manage? If i have  6 to 7 different sections in single table view

Comment: How can I access the section of where the button is pressed if I have to use the objc method?